# Python3 multiprocessing Queue and multiple threads not completing from join() properly?

Tags: python, python-3.6

Attempting to leverage multiprocessing.Queue, and threading.Thread to split up a large number of tasks (healthcheck monitoring of cameras). Given my code below, I'm at a point where I'm trying to know when all cameras have been checked (there are 32,000+), but my output never seems to reach my print statement in main.

Each queue_worker calls "process_camera" which currently does all the healthchecks and returns with a value (this part works!).

When I watch it run, I see it gets to just shy of "complete" and "hangs", so something is blocking or causing it not to finish... I've attempted my get() and my join() statements with timeout arguments, but that seemed to have no effect at all!

I've been staring at this code and the docs for 3 days now... is there something obvious I'm not seeing?

End goal is to healtcheck all 30,000 cameras (loaded into all_cameras at script launch), then "loop" and keep doing it until user aborts script.

```py
def queue_worker(camera_q, result_q):
    '''
    Function takes camera off the queue and calls healthchecks
    '''

    try:
        camera = camera_q.get()
        camera_status, remove_camera = process_camera(camera)

        result_q.put("Success")
        return True
    except queue.Empty:
        logging.info("Queue is empty")
        result_q.put("Fail")
        return False


def process_worker(camera_q, result_q, process_num, stop_event):
    while not stop_event.is_set():
        # Create configured number of threads and provide references to both Queues to each thread
        threads = []
        for i in range(REQUEST_THREADS):
            thread = threading.Thread(target=queue_worker, args=(camera_q, result_q))
            thread.setName("CameraThread-{}".format(i))
            threads.append(thread)
            thread.start()

        for thread in threads:
            thread.join(timeout=120)

        if camera_q.empty():
            num_active = sum([t.is_alive() for t in threads])
            logging.info("[Process {}] << {} >> active threads and << {} >> cameras left to process. << {} >> processed.".format(process_num, num_active, camera_q.qsize(), result_q.qsize()))


def main():
    '''
    Main application entry
    '''

    logging.info("Starting Scan With << " + str(REQUEST_THREADS) + " Threads and " + str(CHILD_PROCESSES) + " Processors >>")
    logging.info("Reference Images Stored During Scan << " + str(store_images) + " >>")

    stop_event = multiprocessing.Event()
    camera_q, result_q = multiprocessing.Queue(), multiprocessing.Queue()

    # Create a Status thread for maintaining process status
    create_status_thread()

    all_cameras = get_oversite_cameras(True)
    for camera in all_cameras:
        camera_q.put(camera)

    logging.info("<< {} >> cameras queued up".format(camera_q.qsize()))

    processes = []
    process_num = 0
    finished_processes = 0
    for i in range(CHILD_PROCESSES):
        process_num += 1
        proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=process_worker, args=(camera_q, result_q, process_num, stop_event))
        proc.start()
        processes.append(proc)

    for proc in processes:
        proc.join()
        finished_processes += 1
        logging.info("{} finished processes".format(finished_pr))

    logging.info("All processes finished")
```

EDIT: Not sure if helpful (visual), but here's an example of my current output when testing with a cap of 2000 cameras:

```
[2018-11-01 23:47:41,854] INFO - MainThread - root - Starting Scan With << 100 Threads and 16 Processors >>
[2018-11-01 23:47:41,854] INFO - MainThread - root - Reference Images Stored During Scan << False >>
[2018-11-01 23:47:41,977] INFO - MainThread - root - << 2000 >> cameras queued up
[2018-11-01 23:47:54,865] INFO - MainThread - root - [Process 3] << 0 >> active threads and << 0 >> cameras left to process. << 1570 >> processed.
[2018-11-01 23:47:56,009] INFO - MainThread - root - [Process 11] << 0 >> active threads and << 0 >> cameras left to process. << 1575 >> processed.
[2018-11-01 23:47:56,210] INFO - MainThread - root - [Process 14] << 0 >> active threads and << 0 >> cameras left to process. << 1579 >> processed.
[2018-11-01 23:47:56,345] INFO - MainThread - root - [Process 9] << 0 >> active threads and << 0 >> cameras left to process. << 1580 >> processed.
[2018-11-01 23:47:59,118] INFO - MainThread - root - [Process 2] << 0 >> active threads and << 0 >> cameras left to process. << 1931 >> processed.
[2018-11-01 23:47:59,637] INFO - MainThread - root - [Process 15] << 0 >> active threads and << 0 >> cameras left to process. << 1942 >> processed.
[2018-11-01 23:48:00,310] INFO - MainThread - root - [Process 8] << 0 >> active threads and << 0 >> cameras left to process. << 1945 >> processed.
[2018-11-01 23:48:00,445] INFO - MainThread - root - [Process 13] << 0 >> active threads and << 0 >> cameras left to process. << 1946 >> processed.
[2018-11-01 23:48:01,391] INFO - MainThread - root - [Process 10] << 0 >> active threads and << 0 >> cameras left to process. << 1949 >> processed.
[2018-11-01 23:48:01,527] INFO - MainThread - root - [Process 5] << 0 >> active threads and << 0 >> cameras left to process. << 1950 >> processed.
[2018-11-01 23:48:01,655] INFO - MainThread - root - [Process 6] << 0 >> active threads and << 0 >> cameras left to process. << 1951 >> processed.
[2018-11-01 23:48:02,519] INFO - MainThread - root - [Process 1] << 0 >> active threads and << 0 >> cameras left to process. << 1954 >> processed.
[2018-11-01 23:48:06,915] INFO - MainThread - root - [Process 12] << 0 >> active threads and << 0 >> cameras left to process. << 1981 >> processed.
[2018-11-01 23:48:27,339] INFO - MainThread - root - [Process 16] << 0 >> active threads and << 0 >> cameras left to process. << 1988 >> processed.
[2018-11-01 23:48:28,762] INFO - MainThread - root - [Process 4] << 0 >> active threads and << 0 >> cameras left to process. << 1989 >> processed.
```

It "hanged" at 1989, just shy of 2000 - this is SO hard to debug!

Comment: Does anyone have an example of a code snippet using multiple processes, AND multiple threads per process? Only thing I can find is people using multiple processes or a Pool, and performing a single task (function) per process.

Answer (score 0):

it's a little hard to answer definitively, because it's not a complete listing. For example, the implementation of create_status_thread() is hidden. This can be especially tricky with troubleshooting deadlocks, because they usually are caused by a particular sequence of access to shared resources, and maybe create_status_thread has one of those. Some suggestions, though:

1. You've already spent significant time on it, so spending time to make a simpler example, with scaffolding code, won't hurt. I suggest getting it working with only dummy methods instead of the actual cameras first. I would also try testing with smaller numbers and proving it works on those first, if you haven't already. It would also make for a better StackOverflow question ;)
2. How much do you need multithreading at all? 30k cameras sounds like a lot, but if each check is 2ms, that's still checking each of them once a minute. Is the complexity worth it? What's your SLA?
3. Process.join() has similar hanging behaviour to your description when there are unprocessed items left on an input queue. This seems possible if you are running until terminal input. You certainly have plenty of input events on queues like camera_q and result_q, from the snippet. See https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#programming-guidelines

> Bear in mind that a process that has put items in a queue will wait before terminating until all the buffered items are fed by the “feeder” thread to the underlying pipe. (The child process can call the Queue.cancel_join_thread method of the queue to avoid this behaviour.)
>
> This means that whenever you use a queue you need to make sure that all items which have been put on the queue will eventually be removed before the process is joined. Otherwise you cannot be sure that processes which have put items on the queue will terminate. Remember also that non-daemonic processes will be joined automatically.

The above link includes a blocking example where join() is called before get(). It seems like that might be possible in your code depending on execution order, as you call get() inside the process_worker().

4. multiprocessing.Pool might be a simpler way to manage a pool of workers. See https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#using-a-pool-of-workers

Comment: Thanks for the response @conflated. The create_service_thread() is a separate thread and works without issue (no interaction with this queue). I've attempted a wittled-down version (3000 cameras), and have even tried using Pool. Pool worked, but it pools processes, which prevented me from using the 100+ threads in my worker process (unless my implementation was wrong). Each camera can take up to a minute or more (with timeouts), so it isn't super quick (2ms). My end goal is to complete all cameras under 5 minutes. I"m very close to this now, but not being able to detect which ones are hanging.